# new PSU causes issues to keyboard

Tags: keyboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

A year ago, I replaced the old PSU that burned out with a new one, but this one and even though everything works fine, the keyboard doesn't write well. For example, when I press the letter "a" sometimes it writes it twice or more or does not write it at all (Tried to replace the keyboard with another one but same problem). But I noticed during that period that the keyboard works normally when I touch the case or any other computer elements with my hand or feet.
If there is a solution to this problem, I do not want to spend all the time touching the computer to write or use the keyboard. Thank you to everyone for contributing to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that touching the case avoids the problem, I would conclude
that your new PSU causes static electricity to accumulate in your device.
When touching the case, this electricity is earthed through your body.

There is either a problem with your new PSU, or more probably a
problem with how it's installed. Some unporotected wires may not be
isolated enough or may pass too near to the PSU.

I can't give precise instructions, so I suggest to have someone
knowledgeable have a look at how the PSU is installed, in view of
verifying the installation, and whether the PSU is defective
or if some more isolation could help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your case grounding & earthing.

Grounding: to make sure your PSU is making a good electrical connection from its case to the computer's case & that no stray cables/wires are touching the case that should not.

Earthing: to ensure the entire computer is correctly earthed at the mains.

The issue sounds like you have a potential differential between computer & earth; you are then periodically providing a path to earth. In extreme circumstances this could be dangerous or even fatal.
If you don't feel competent to tackle this yourself, take it to a service engineer.

[I'm using UK definitions of ground & earth, which differentiate better than the US convention of using 'ground' for both meanings.]